# PyCharm Debug Variable view: disabling variable address

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've been debugging with PyCharm for a long time now but I can't seem to figure out how to disable these long numbers that appear after a dictionary key. I'm assuming the number represents some memory address offset but it's really annoying because it sends the value of the variable off the screen and I have to scroll to see it with the way I have my windows set up.

Here's a screenshot of an example. These are keys inside dictionary. Normal variables, including the parent dict itself don't have these numbers attached.

[image: Screenshot of dictionary keys with long unknown number next to each.]

Comment: I don't have them turned on, but I have clicked every button and setting in hope to turn it on. I think they represent the `id` of and object. If you right click on some variable, for example `member_id` and choose *Evaluate Expression* and type `id(member_id)`, you would get result `140114253011568`. There is a section in Data Views on Debugger for enabling `id` and `name`, but they seem not to respond when applying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was fixed in 2019.3 with https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37497 The early access version can be found https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/